# Show "out of stock" when i add order manually in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, orders

When i add this code to my child theme function.php it prevents me as admin to add the product when i create a order and shows an alert "Product out of stock"

I want only the alert to be show if the product is out of stock and to not prevent me(as admin) from adding that product.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_validation', 'rmg_woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_validation', 10, 4 );
function rmg_woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_validation( $validation_error, $product, $order, $qty ) {
    if ( $validation_error && !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $validation_error->add( 'product-out-of-stock', __('Product Out of Stock', 'woocommerce') );
    }
    if ( $validation_error && ( $product->get_stock_quantity() < $qty ) ) {
        $validation_error->add( 'product-low-stock', __('Product low of Stock', 'woocommerce') );
    }
    return $validation_error;
}
```

I tried almost everthing and no success!

Comment: when your product inventory quantity is 0 then it will show "Product Out of Stock" alert on order create admin side